# How to disable free form user input allow drop down only

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

I have an input from to choose a time. But I want the user to be able to change the input value only from drop down and not to be able to freely type on it

```
<div>
  <input id="Time"/>
</div>
```

Comment: are you looking at using html5 time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
$("#Time").kendoDatePicker();
```

`$('#Time').attr('disabled','disabled');`

Other way to do it in html itself would be:

```
<input id="Time" onkeydown="return false;" />
```

Comment: `<input id="Time" onkeydown="return false;" />` worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`select`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) tag instead of the `input` tag

[Here is a demo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select)

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x4dA9/602/) using [KendoDateTime Picker](http://jsfiddle.net/x4dA9/602/)

```
<input id="Time" readonly/>
```

I used the [readonly](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp) option for the input to disable input

Comment: I use a kendoDateTimePicker for the dropdown .I don't have options on my input

Comment: I've updated the answer for the date time picker problem

Comment: I like your solution: But what is I want to define smth like this:|

`$("#datePicker").kendoDatePicker({
    close: function() {
              interval: 5,
                culture: "da-DK",
                depth:"month"
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

[This is what you are looking for](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select)

Comment: I use a kendoDateTimePicker for the dropdown .I don't have options on my input

Answer (score 0):

To disable the user from freely typing in the Text Box.

```
<input id="Time" disabled/>
```

[Asking For somethin like This DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xbMRrG)